# How to send float values from Python to Arduino LCD?

Tags: python, arduino

My classmate and I have been working on this project based on this Instructables article https://www.instructables.com/id/Building-a-Simple-Pendulum-and-Measuring-Motion-Wi/, our idea is to make a pendulum, calculate the g force (from the pendulum's period) and then show its value on a LCD we got connected to the Arduino. We got the code up and running (it calculates the period), and we understood that the Arduino has to do some type of conversion (utf-8) to pass the values it gets from the potentiometer to Python. However when we try to send the value we get from calculating the period of the graph back to the arduino and show it on the LCD, it shows 634 or other similiar values, we tried to instead of the decode it does initially, go the other way around with encode, but it won't work. We can't check the value it is getting from the serial, because the serial monitor simply doesn't open while the python script is running. What is the most pratical way we can use to "transfer" floats calculated in a Python script to the Arduino, so that we can calculate g and show it on the screen. Many forums advice to instead of transferring the floats, convert them to strings since it would be easy for the arduino to receive, but we aren't sure that would even work. I'm sure this is a simple question, but we just can't seem to get it. If you find anything else wrong with the code please let me know, we know it's a bit sketchy. Thanks.

Python code:

```
arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200, timeout=.1) #Open connection to Arduino
samples = 200 #We will take this many readings
angle_data = np.zeros(samples) #Creates a vector for our angle data
time_data = np.zeros(samples) #Creates a vector of same length for time
i = 0;
calibrate = 123 #Value to zero potentiometer reading when pendulum is motionless, read from Arduino
while i!=samples:
    data = arduino.readline()[0:-2].decode('utf-8')
    if data:
        angle_data[i] = (float(data) - calibrate)*math.pi/180
        time_data[i] = time.perf_counter()
        print(angle_data[i])
        i = i + 1

min = np.min(angle_data)
print (min)
min_pos, = np.where(angle_data == min)
min_x = time_data[min_pos]
print (min_x)

nos_left = int(min_pos)
max = 0;
for i in range(nos_left,200):
   if angle_data[i] > max: max = angle_data[i]

print (max)
max_pos, = np.where(angle_data == max)
max_x = time_data[max_pos]
print (max_x)

period = (max_x - min_x) * 2
print (period)

gforce = (0.165 * 4 * (math.pi) * (math.pi)) / ((period) * (period))
print (gforce)

value_g = arduino.write(gforce)

plt.plot(time_data,angle_data,'ro')
plt.axis([0,time_data[samples-1],-math.pi,math.pi])
plt.xlabel("Time (seconds)")
plt.ylabel("Angle (Radians)")
plt.title("Pendulum Motion - Measured with Arduino and potentiometer")
plt.show()
arduino.close()
```

Arduino code

```
const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

int period = 0;

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  Serial.begin(115200); // use the same baud-rate as the python side
        pinMode(A0,INPUT);
        lcd.print("    Pendulo    ");
        int gforce = 0;

}

void loop() {
  // set the cursor to column 0, line 1
  // (note: line 1 is the second row, since counting begins with 0):
  // print the number of seconds since reset:


        int degrees;
        degrees = getDegree();
        Serial.println(degrees);
        Serial.println("\n");
        delay(50);

        if (Serial.available() > 0) {
                // read the incoming byte:
                gforce = Serial.read();

                Serial.print("I received: ");
                Serial.println(gforce, DEC);
        }

        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(gforce);


}

int getDegree()
{
  int sensor_value = analogRead(A0);
  float voltage;
  voltage = (float)sensor_value*5/1023;
  float degrees = (voltage*300)/5;
  return degrees;
}
```

Comment: most if not all serial interfaces transfer data byte-wise. So either you split your float values into bytes and fiddle them together on the receiving end or you simply send them as a string.

Comment: As your arduino just has to show that  gforce  on the lcd it might be easiest, to send that as a text, and format it on the python side already. Anyway, it's more than reading one byte only.  And add an end-of-message character into that text. Could be a newline, or any other char not to expect in your number text, and should be the last one of the transmission.

Comment: Take a look at the [parseFloat()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ParseFloat) method for Arduino Serial (as opposed to `Serial.read()`).

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a good case for the Arduino Serial's [parseFloat()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ParseFloat) method:

```
if (Serial.available() > 0) {

    /* instead of Serial.read(), use: */

    gforce = Serial.parseFloat();

    Serial.print("I received: ");
    Serial.println(gforce, DEC);
}
```

Essentially, it pulls out anything that looks like a float within the received serial data, even if it's mixed with other non-numerical characters.

It also works with Software Serial.